# Contiguous regions in web map services

Tags: google-maps, bing-maps, yahoo-maps

Google Maps can't calculate [a route that crosses Equator - Colombia borders](http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Tulcan,+Carchi,+Ecuador&daddr=Ipiales+-+Narino,+Colombia&hl=en&sll=2.98379,-75.61733&sspn=7.663269,13.392334&geocode=FZNiDAAdrRte-ylN69XnumgpjjGNODOfsXMuLQ%3B&oq=Ipiales,Colombia&mra=ls&t=m&z=10), and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aGoogle_Maps_zusammenh%C3%A4ngende_Regionen_%281%29.png) analysis from a Wikipedia user shows the regions it considers contiguous. It is possible to compute a route in Yahoo! Maps from [Punta Arenas to Maracaibo](http://maps.yahoo.com/#q=Punta+Arenas+%28Magallanes%29%2C+Chile&conf=1&start=1&lat=-53.22247975316637&lon=-71.103515625&zoom=3&mvt=m&trf=0&unit=km&q1=Punta+Arenas+%28Magallanes%29%2C+Chile&q2=Maracaibo%2C+Venezuela), but not to Alaska.

Why does this services have such limitations? Is there a similar analysis of contiguous regions for other web routing services?

Answer (score 1):

The closest similar "analysis" I know of for Bing Maps is the table given at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd435699.aspx, which shows the routing capabilities provided for each country (Basic/Full).

Interestingly, even though both Ecuador and Colombia are listed as having only "Basic" routing functionality, Bing Maps does correctly find the route between Tulcan and Ipiales shown in your first example: http://www.bing.com/maps/#Y3A9MC44MjE2NDA5OTgxMjgxNn4tNzcuNjg2OTIzOTgwNzEyODkmbHZsPTEzJnN0eT1yJnJ0cD1wb3MuMC44MjE1MjBfLTc3LjczMjE3MF9UdWxjJUMzJUExbiUyQyUyMEVjdWFkb3JfX19lX35wb3MuMC44MjE3NjJfLTc3LjY0MTY3OF9JcGlhbGVzJTJDJTIwQ29sb21iaWFfX19lXyZtb2RlPUQmcnRvcD0wfjB+MH4=

I guess the reason why routing capability must be compartmentalised into discrete countries is because the data required is gathered from national agencies (e.g. government datasets) and managed/updated on a per-country basis - but this obviously creates an interesting problem for routing across borders, as in your examples.

I have to be honest and say that I've never really considered the issue before, so I'd like to thank you for raising the question!

---

**Update**: Note that, according to the spreadsheet linked from https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#whatcountries, Google Maps doesn't support directions *within* either Ecuador or Colombia either - let alone a route that crosses between them!

Comment: That's odd: its possible to obtain routes within those countries and across other Ecuador borders. Is it ok to dup this question at the Stack GIS site? I've just found it through your profile.

Comment: Sure - you can duplicate this question wherever you like! Incidentally, I also blogged about it, here: http://alastaira.wordpress.com/2012/05/27/routing-sans-frontires/